# How can open a folder on user click in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I want to open a folder dialog that is located under the root of my application whenever a user clicks on the web page. The idea is to make an ajax call to the server and then the server returns by ***showing to*** ***the user a file system browser dialog showing all files in a folder on the server .***
The only thing that i am missing is the server-side part. This is what the server-side looks like but it is not complete, looking for idea...

```
 public ActionResult OpenFolder()
 {

    var folderContents = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/")); //The folder to open is named Uploads
    return Content(folderContents);
 }
```

Comment: What do you want the user to see?  A file system browser dialog showing all files in a folder on the server?

Comment: Exactly! I want show to the user a browser dialog folder on the server

Answer (score 0):

You will need to render your own file browser control.  A web page cannot open the client computer's file browser dialog because of security reasons.  As an example, loop through the files server side, build a json string with file names, then feed that json back to the browser.  In the client side code, use javascript to render a tree view or even a simple list from the returned json.  Or, google tree view controls, read up on how they work, then plug the returned json into it as a data source.

Comment: Hello mate ! I appreciate some much for the insights. I am going to google how tree view controls work. Thanks a lot mate